# Exchange за натом

Tags: windows-server, exchange

Как организовать полноценную работу Exchange 2016 извне, если он спрятан за натом?

Ранее никогда его не использовал, но, насколько я понял, у меня не работает ActiveSynс, так как он использует RPC и динамические порты. Такой проброс портов я сделать не смогу.

С чем я могу столкнуться при таком варианте развертывания?

Может быть, есть смысл в качестве внешнего фаервола использовать тоже Windows Server? раньше был ISA, вроде, но, судя по доступному софту в MSDN, он закончил свое существование в 2006 году. Есть ли ему замена? И есть ли смысл. Так как что-то мне подсказывает, что проблему динамических портов это не решит.

Comment: вот [рекомендую почитать](https://habrahabr.ru/post/302068/) очень подробно

Answer (score 1):

Правильнее всего - это поднять сервер с ролью **Edge Transport** и разместить его за натом, в DMZ, куда смогут подключаться внешние отправители. Сервер Edge будет связан с вашим внутреннем сервером подпиской и пересылать все сообщения внутрь. В свою очередь внутренний сервер будет пересылать все сообщения на Edge сервер, который будет доставлять из внешним получателям.

Архитектура этого решения показана на картинке.

[image: Архитектура Exchange 2016]

Обратите внимание, что Edge сервер тоже стоит располагать за firewall-ом.
Что касается публикации Вашего сервера для доступа через Outlook, Web Browser (OWA), или мобильные устройства, то тут предлагается использовать firewall, который умеет пробрасывать порты.